# Search .zip files for sizes

Tags: search, zip, archiving, ls

I have a directory with many .zip files. I wish to search through them to match an uncompressed file size (I am trying to find which .zip my file originated in, and the name's been changed). IDEALLY, I could say "ls -z /zipfiles | grep "123456" and ls would treat the .zip as a directory. Fuse might be made to work, but it only works with single files and is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work?

```
for i in *.zip ; do
  echo $i;
  unzip -l ${i} | grep "123456";
done
```